# python-swiftclient broken pipe in requests

Tags: python, python-requests, openstack-swift

I'm trying to incorporate `python-swiftclient` into my clumsy API and I'm having some trouble. Here is the simplest, stripped down code:

```
import swiftclient

url = "url-goes-here"
user = "my-user-goes-here"
key = "my-key-goes-here"

def get_token():
    return swiftclient.get_auth(url, user, key)[1]

def upload():
    theFile = open("/home/ivica/thefile.pdf", 'rb')
    token = get_token()

    resp = swiftclient.put_object(url,token,'test6','some name.pdf',theFile)

    print resp

upl()
```

The file is being uploaded for ~30 seconds and then this error pops up:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 372, in send
    raise ConnectionError(sockerr, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: What version of python-swiftclient are you using? This seems to have been [fixed already](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-swiftclient/+bug/1131142) but this could also be an entirely different bug.

Comment: Yes, the newer version of `python-swiftclient` does not produce this. On the other hand, something is wrong with my authentification, but thats a whole another issue. Thank you.